# Entropy of X conditioned on a noisy version X+Y

Tags: conditional-probability, information-theory, entropy

I am interested in calculating $H(X|Z)$ for $Z=X+Y$ is a noisy version of $X$.

Initially, I was thinking since $Z$ is just a noisy version of $X$ then $H(X|X+Y) = H(Y)$  is just the uncertainty in the additive noise applied to $X$.

But, when I played through an example, I found different results.

I am considering

$$P(X) = \begin{cases}
    \frac{1}{2}, &X=0\\
    \frac{1}{2}, &X=1
\end{cases}$$

$$P(Y) = \begin{cases}
    (1-p), &Y=0\\
    p, &Y=1
\end{cases}$$

Then

\begin{array}{llll|ll}
X &Y &Z &prob \\ \hline
0 &0 &0 &\frac{1}{2}(1-p)\\
0 &1 &1 &\frac{1}{2}p\\
1 &0 &1 &\frac{1}{2}(1-p)\\
1 & 1 &2 &\frac{1}{2}p\\
\end{array}

From this we can find $P(Z)$,

$$P(Z) = \begin{cases}
    \frac{1}{2}(1-p), &Z=0\\
    \frac{1}{2}, &Z=1\\
    \frac{1}{2}p, &Z=2
\end{cases}$$

Then calculating $P(X|Z)$,

\begin{array}{l|ll}
P(X|Z) &0 &1 \\ \hline
0 &1 &0 \\
1 &p &(1-p) \\
2 &0 &1
\end{array}

Now Finding $H(X|Z)$,

$$H(X|Z) = \sum_z p(z) H(X|Z=z)$$

$$= p(z=1)H_b(p,1-p)$$

$$= \frac{1}{2}H(Y)$$

Is this the correct calculation? I thought that I had read somewhere that $H(X|X+Y) = H(Y)$, but according to this example its not exactly true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not true that $H(X|X+Y) = H(Y)$ - your calculation is a counterexample. What is true is that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $H(X+Y|X) = H(Y)$ (exercise - show this), perhaps you're getting confused with this.

In fact, we can show that if $Y$ and $X+Y$ are not independnet, then $H(X|X+Y) < H(Y).$

Since $(x,y) \mapsto (x, x+y) $ is a bijection, $H(X,Y) = H(X,X+Y)$, and by the chain rule, $$ H(X,Y) = H(X, X+Y) = H(X+Y) + H(X|X+Y).$$ But, by the chain rule, it's also true that  $H(X,Y) = H(X|Y)+ H(Y).$ But then $$ H(X|X+Y) = H(Y) + H(X|Y) - H(X+Y)\\ = H(Y) + H(X+Y|Y) - H(X+Y) \\
= H(Y) - I(Y;X+Y).$$ Due to non-independence the final mutual information is non-zero, showing that $H(X|X+Y) < H(Y)$.